# nginx rewrite url only with certain subdomain

Tags: regex, nginx, configuration, url-rewriting

I am trying to make my nginx rewriting all the urls with certain subdomain (m.example.com) to add string: ?theme=XXX to the end of the file

In my nignx server configuration i have:

```
    server{
      server_name example.com m.example.com y.example.com 
      (...)
    }
```

Now, I want to rewrite all http requests going ONLY through m.example.com to add to the end of the url ?theme=XXX

I have the following rewrite:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?theme=XXX? break;
```

but i don't know how to make rewriting only requests from m.example.com (not from all server names)

Comment: You could use different server configuration blocks.

Comment: but following rewrite don't want to work for me

Comment: Use separate server block. Copy all the `(...)` to new server block